# deserialization of nested JSON from Cratejoy

Tags: vb.net, json.net, deserialization, cratejoy

I'm trying to deserialize below JSON from Cratejoy and get a list of shipment_id's into DataGridView, but it doesn't seem to do it for me.

JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "next": null,
  "prev": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "adjusted_ordered_at": "2019-08-14T14:01:40Z",
      "created_at": "2019-08-14T14:01:40Z",
      "customer_id": 398862090,
      "feedback_responses": [],
      "fulfillments": [
        {
          "adjusted_fulfillment_date": "2019-08-14T14:01:40Z",
          "cycle_number": 0,
          "fulfillment_date": "2019-08-14T14:01:40Z",
          "id": 2349318760,
          "instance": {
            "deleted": false,
            "gift": false,
            "id": 1445951944,
            "images": [],
            "inventory": null,
            "price": 0,
            "product": {
              "deleted": false,
              "id": 1445951937,
              "mp_visible": true,
              "name": "Monthly CULTURE Box ",
              "single_purchasable": false
            },
            "product_id": 1445951937,
            "ship_weight": 10.0,
            "sku": "SQ6217913",
            "term_prices": [
              {
                "id": 1445951946,
                "instance_id": 1445951944,
                "price": 1699,
                "term_id": 1445951938,
                "type": "product_instance_subscription_type_term_price"
              },
              {
                "id": 1445951951,
                "instance_id": 1445951944,
                "price": 4899,
                "term_id": 1445951939,
                "type": "product_instance_subscription_type_term_price"
              },
              {
                "id": 1445951952,
                "instance_id": 1445951944,
                "price": 9599,
                "term_id": 1445951940,
                "type": "product_instance_subscription_type_term_price"
              },
              {
                "id": 1445951953,
                "instance_id": 1445951944,
                "price": 18299,
                "term_id": 1445951941,
                "type": "product_instance_subscription_type_term_price"
              }
            ],
            "type": "product_instance",
            "variants": []
          },
          "is_test": false,
          "order": {
            "card_refunded_amount": 0,
            "credit_applied": 0,
            "customer": {
              "country": "GB",
              "email": "alice.smith99@gmail.com",
              "first_name": "Sarah",
              "id": 398862090,
              "last_name": "Chug",
              "location": "GB",
              "name": "Sarah Chug",
              "type": "customer"
            },
            "customer_id": 398862090,
            "financial_status": "paid",
            "fulfillment_status": "fulfilled",
            "gift_card_discount": 0,
            "gift_message": null,
            "gift_renewal_notif": false,
            "gross_shipping": 0,
            "id": 2349292405,
            "is_gift": false,
            "is_renewal": false,
            "is_test": false,
            "note": null,
            "order_gift_info": null,
            "placed_at": "2019-08-14T13:39:49Z",
            "prorated_charge": null,
            "received_gift": null,
            "refund_applied": null,
            "refunded_amount": 0,
            "sent_gift": null,
            "status": "closed",
            "store_id": 147108660,
            "sub_total": 1699,
            "subscriptions": [
              {
                "autorenew": true,
                "billing": {
                  "id": 1445951935,
                  "rebill_day": 15,
                  "rebill_months": 1,
                  "rebill_weeks": null,
                  "rebill_window": 10,
                  "store_id": 147108660,
                  "type": "product_billing"
                },
                "billing_name": "Monthly",
                "credit": null,
                "customer": {
                  "country": "GB",
                  "email": "alice.Smith99@gmail.com",
                  "first_name": "Sarah",
                  "id": 398862090,
                  "last_name": "Chug",
                  "location": "GB",
                  "name": "Sarah Chug",
                  "type": "customer"
                },
                "end_date": "2019-09-15T00:00:00Z",
                "id": 2349318754,
                "is_test": false,
                "merchant_billing": null,
                "note": null,
                "product_billing_id": 1445951935,
                "skipped_date": null,
                "source": 3,
                "start_date": "2019-08-14T14:01:40Z",
                "status": "active",
                "store_id": 147108660,
                "term": {
                  "description": "Charged every month",
                  "enabled": true,
                  "id": 1445951938,
                  "images": [],
                  "name": "Month to Month",
                  "num_cycles": 1,
                  "type": "subscription_type_term"
                },
                "type": "subscription"
              }
            ],
            "total": 1699,
            "total_app_fees": null,
            "total_label_cost": null,
            "total_pending_fees": null,
            "total_price": 1699,
            "total_shipping": 0,
            "total_tax": 0,
            "transaction_fee": 30,
            "transaction_fee_status": 1,
            "type": "order"
          },
          "shipment_id": 2349318762,
          "shipping": 0,
          "status": "open",
          "subscription_id": 2349318754,
          "tax": 0,
          "test": false,
          "total_cycles": 1,
          "type": "fulfillment"
        }
      ],
      "id": 2349318762,
      "is_gift": false,
      "is_test": false,
      "labels": [],
      "ship_address": {
        "city": "london",
        "company": "",
        "country": "GB",
        "icon": "United-Kingdom.png",
        "id": 2349292377,
        "phone_number": "7835888303",
        "state": "",
        "status": 3,
        "status_message": "Cannot verify international addresses.",
        "street": "6 victoria gardens, heston",
        "to": "ALICE Kingdom",
        "type": "address",
        "unit": "heston",
        "zip_code": "TW59DE"
      },
      "shipped_at": null,
      "status": "unshipped",
      "target_at": "2019-08-14T14:01:40Z",
      "tracking_number": null,
      "type": "shipment",
      "url": "/v1/shipments/2349318762/"
    },
    {
      "adjusted_ordered_at": "2019-08-14T15:39:32Z",
      "created_at": "2019-08-14T15:39:32Z",
      "customer_id": 2349459101,
      "feedback_responses": [],
      "fulfillments": [
        {
          "adjusted_fulfillment_date": "2019-08-14T15:39:32Z",
          "cycle_number": null,
          "fulfillment_date": "2019-08-14T15:39:32Z",
          "id": 2349459176,
          "instance": {
            "deleted": false,
            "gift": false,
            "id": 2347700148,
            "images": [],
            "inventory": {
              "confidence": 10,
              "id": 2347700153,
              "out_of_stock_purchases": false,
              "product_instance_id": 2347700148,
              "quantity_on_hand": 13,
              "track_inventory": true,
              "type": "product_inventory"
            },
            "price": 1499,
            "product": {
              "deleted": false,
              "id": 2347700147,
              "mp_visible": true,
              "name": "Inspire Me Korea TRAVEL GUIDE BUNDLE [SAVE 17%]",
              "single_purchasable": true
            },
            "product_id": 2347700147,
            "ship_weight": 0.0,
            "sku": "SQ7195254",
            "term_prices": [],
            "type": "product_instance",
            "variants": []
          },
          "is_test": false,
          "order": {
            "card_refunded_amount": 0,
            "credit_applied": 0,
            "customer": {
              "country": "FR",
              "email": "delaunaylily22@gmail.com",
              "first_name": "Margaret",
              "id": 2349459101,
              "last_name": "Tatcher",
              "location": "FR",
              "name": "Margaret Tatcher",
              "type": "customer"
            },
            "customer_id": 2349459101,
            "financial_status": "paid",
            "fulfillment_status": "unfilled",
            "gift_card_discount": 0,
            "gift_message": null,
            "gift_renewal_notif": false,
            "gross_shipping": 699,
            "id": 2349459127,
            "is_gift": false,
            "is_renewal": false,
            "is_test": false,
            "note": null,
            "order_gift_info": null,
            "placed_at": "2019-08-14T15:39:28Z",
            "prorated_charge": null,
            "received_gift": null,
            "refund_applied": null,
            "refunded_amount": 0,
            "sent_gift": null,
            "status": "closed",
            "store_id": 147108660,
            "sub_total": 3897,
            "subscriptions": [
              {
                "autorenew": true,
                "billing": {
                  "id": 1445951935,
                  "rebill_day": 15,
                  "rebill_months": 1,
                  "rebill_weeks": null,
                  "rebill_window": 10,
                  "store_id": 147108660,
                  "type": "product_billing"
                },
                "billing_name": "Monthly",
                "credit": null,
                "customer": {
                  "country": "FR",
                  "email": "delaunaylily@gmail.com",
                  "first_name": "Margeret",
                  "id": 2349459101,
                  "last_name": "Delaunay",
                  "location": "FR",
                  "name": "Margaret Tatcher",
                  "type": "customer"
                },
                "end_date": "2019-09-15T00:00:00Z",
                "id": 2349459172,
                "is_test": false,
                "merchant_billing": null,
                "note": null,
                "product_billing_id": 1445951935,
                "skipped_date": null,
                "source": 3,
                "start_date": "2019-08-14T15:39:32Z",
                "status": "active",
                "store_id": 147108660,
                "term": {
                  "description": "Charged every month",
                  "enabled": true,
                  "id": 1445951938,
                  "images": [],
                  "name": "Month to Month",
                  "num_cycles": 1,
                  "type": "subscription_type_term"
                },
                "type": "subscription"
              }
            ],
            "total": 3643,
            "total_app_fees": null,
            "total_label_cost": null,
            "total_pending_fees": null,
            "total_price": 2944,
            "total_shipping": 699,
            "total_tax": 0,
            "transaction_fee": 54,
            "transaction_fee_status": 1,
            "type": "order"
          },
          "shipment_id": 2349459174,
          "shipping": 0,
          "status": "open",
          "subscription_id": null,
          "tax": 0,
          "test": false,
          "total_cycles": null,
          "type": "fulfillment"
        },
        {
          "adjusted_fulfillment_date": "2019-08-14T15:39:32Z",
          "cycle_number": 0,
          "fulfillment_date": "2019-08-14T15:39:32Z",
          "id": 2349459177,
          "instance": {
            "deleted": false,
            "gift": false,
            "id": 1445951944,
            "images": [],
            "inventory": null,
            "price": 0,
            "product": {
              "deleted": false,
              "id": 1445951937,
              "mp_visible": true,
              "name": "Monthly CULTURE Box ",
              "single_purchasable": false
            },
            "product_id": 1445951937,
            "ship_weight": 10.0,
            "sku": "SQ6217913",
            "term_prices": [
              {
                "id": 1445951946,
                "instance_id": 1445951944,
                "price": 1699,
                "term_id": 1445951938,
                "type": "product_instance_subscription_type_term_price"
              },
              {
                "id": 1445951951,
                "instance_id": 1445951944,
                "price": 4899,
                "term_id": 1445951939,
                "type": "product_instance_subscription_type_term_price"
              },
              {
                "id": 1445951952,
                "instance_id": 1445951944,
                "price": 9599,
                "term_id": 1445951940,
                "type": "product_instance_subscription_type_term_price"
              },
              {
                "id": 1445951953,
                "instance_id": 1445951944,
                "price": 18299,
                "term_id": 1445951941,
                "type": "product_instance_subscription_type_term_price"
              }
            ],
            "type": "product_instance",
            "variants": []
          },
          "is_test": false,
          "order": {
            "card_refunded_amount": 0,
            "credit_applied": 0,
            "customer_id": 2349459102,
            "financial_status": "paid",
            "fulfillment_status": "unfilled",
            "gift_card_discount": 0,
            "gift_message": null,
            "gift_renewal_notif": false,
            "gross_shipping": 699,
            "id": 2349459123,
            "is_gift": false,
            "is_renewal": false,
            "is_test": false,
            "note": null,
            "placed_at": "2019-08-14T15:39:28Z",
            "prorated_charge": null,
            "refund_applied": null,
            "refunded_amount": 0,
            "status": "closed",
            "store_id": 147108660,
            "sub_total": 3897,
            "total": 3643,
            "total_app_fees": null,
            "total_label_cost": null,
            "total_pending_fees": null,
            "total_price": 2944,
            "total_shipping": 699,
            "total_tax": 0,
            "transaction_fee": 54,
            "transaction_fee_status": 1,
            "type": "order"
          },
          "shipment_id": 2349459174,
          "shipping": 699,
          "status": "open",
          "subscription_id": 2349459172,
          "tax": 0,
          "test": false,
          "total_cycles": 1,
          "type": "fulfillment"
        }
      ],
      "id": 2349459174,
      "is_gift": false,
      "is_test": false,
      "labels": [],
      "ship_address": {
        "city": "Chambray-lès-Tours",
        "company": "",
        "country": "FR",
        "icon": "France.png",
        "id": 2349459103,
        "phone_number": "06 58 71 19 33 ",
        "state": "",
        "status": 3,
        "status_message": "Cannot verify international addresses.",
        "street": "35 rue Vasco de Gama",
        "to": "John Smith",
        "type": "address",
        "unit": "",
        "zip_code": "37170"
      },
      "shipped_at": null,
      "status": "unshipped",
      "target_at": "2019-08-14T15:39:32Z",
      "tracking_number": null,
      "type": "shipment",
      "url": "/v1/shipments/2349459174/"
    }
  ]
}
```

and my code looks like this:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim url As String = "https://api.cratejoy.com/v1/shipments/?with=fulfillments&created_at__gt=2019-08-01T10:00:00Z"

        'make a call
        Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
        Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic logpassword")
        Request.Proxy = Nothing

        'get a response
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim Response As HttpWebResponse = Request.GetResponse
        Dim ResponseStream As System.IO.Stream = Response.GetResponseStream
        Dim StreamReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(ResponseStream)
        Dim jobj As String = StreamReader.ReadToEnd 'response
        Dim Status As String = Response.StatusCode
        Dim ContentLength As String = Response.ContentLength
        Dim StatusDescription As String = Response.StatusDescription
        MsgBox("Status: " & Status & vbNewLine +
               "Content Length: " & ContentLength & vbNewLine +
               "Status Description: " & StatusDescription & vbNewLine)
        If Status = 404 Or Status = 400 Then
            MsgBox("Error downloading data!")
            Exit Sub
        End If


        Label1.Text = jobj 'show me the JSON - works for smaller JSONs but doesn't want to show the big ones??

        'Deserialize
        Dim SObject As New List(Of Result)()
        SObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Result))(jobj)

        Dim a As Integer = 0

        For Each item As Object In SObject
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {a + 1, item.shipment_id.ToString})
            a += 1
        Next

    End Sub
```

My Classes:

```
Public Class Root
    Public Property results As List(Of Result)()
End Class

Public Class Result
    Public Property adjusted_ordered_at As DateTime
    Public Property created_at As DateTime
    Public Property customer_id As Integer
    Public Property feedback_responses As Object()
    Public Property fulfillments As List(Of Fulfillment)()
    Public Property id As Long
    Public Property is_gift As Boolean
    Public Property is_test As Boolean
    Public Property labels As Object()
    Public Property ship_address As ShipAddress
    Public Property shipped_at As Object
    Public Property status As String
    Public Property target_at As DateTime
    Public Property tracking_number As Object
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property url As String
End Class

Public Class Fulfillment
    Public Property adjusted_fulfillment_date As DateTime
    Public Property cycle_number As Integer
    Public Property fulfillment_date As DateTime
    Public Property id As Long
    Public Property instance As Instance
    Public Property is_test As Boolean
    Public Property order As Order
    Public Property shipment_id As String
    Public Property shipping As Integer
    Public Property status As String
    Public Property subscription_id As Long
    Public Property tax As Integer
    Public Property test As Boolean
    Public Property total_cycles As Integer
    Public Property type As String
End Class
```

I'm guessing something is wrong with Classes, but I've tried on many different ways and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Also, does anybody know if I can filter on Cratejoy to only show 'unshipped' shipments? I'm sure i can, but their instruction on http://docs.cratejoy.com/docs/filtering-and-searching2 doesn't want to work with address:
https://api.cratejoy.com/v1/shipments/?fulfillments.status=open&created_at__gt=2019-08-14T14:00:00Z

One other thing - too big JSON doesn't want to show on Label1.Text, how can i see what my app has downloaded ??

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Re: Label1.Text = jobj  Could always just use a watch, or console.Writeline or output it to a file or use object visualizers with breakpoints

Comment: Your model's structure is missing many elements, at least you didn't post them here. The JSON you're showing cannot be deserialized as a `List(Of Result)`. You need an upper level object that contains a property of type `List(Of Result)` and some others (`count`, `next`, `prev`). After that, filtering `Result.status` is trivial.

Comment: @Jimi, there is Root with list of results and I tried it, but then shipment_id is nested in fulfillments in results in root and how do i deserialize that??

Comment: You have to deserialize the whole thing (everything you get from the Server), then filter the results the way you want to *see* them. LINQ is the commonly used to perform filtering on this kind of objects. For example, to return all `Result` object that contain at least one `open` fulfillment, you can write: `Dim fullfillmentOpen = Root.Results.Where(Function(res) res.Fulfillments.Any(Function(fl) fl.Status.Equals("open"))).ToList()`. Or `Result` objects where `status` is `"unshipped"`: `Dim unshipped = Root.Results.Where(Function(res) res.Status.Equals("unshipped")).ToList()`.

Comment: You can pre-define a number of these queries to perform filtering tasks that you use often and other, more generic, that accept parameters, to filter the data based on different requirements. If you don't know LINQ, it's time to get acquainted. It's quite easy to handle once you get hold of it.

Comment: All right. If you have troubles, ping back. Post what you tried and I'll give you a hand if something doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this also:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("shipment_id", "Shipment ID")

        Dim ParseJSON As JObject = JObject.Parse(TextBox1.Text)

        For Each result As JToken In ParseJSON("results")
            For Each fullfilmentitem As JToken In result("fulfillments")
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(fullfilmentitem("shipment_id"))
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

---

Or for both statuses:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("shipment_id", "Unshipped Shipment")
        DataGridView2.Columns.Add("shipment_id", "Shipped Shipment")

        Dim ParseJSON As JObject = JObject.Parse(TextBox1.Text)

        For Each result As JToken In ParseJSON("results")
            If result("status").ToString.Equals("unshipped") Then
                For Each fullfilmentitem As JToken In result("fulfillments")
                    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(fullfilmentitem("shipment_id"))
                Next
            Else 'shipped
                For Each fullfilmentitem As JToken In result("fulfillments")
                    DataGridView2.Rows.Add(fullfilmentitem("shipment_id"))
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

Comment: You can check some of my other answers on JSON for different kinds of ways to do stuff with it (for hints).

Comment: now i can get the list of all shipments, i know how to get 1 shipment JSON, but i need to get all "sku" to DataGridView, this is in fulfillments -> instances -> sku, I'm trying to go with:      For Each result As JToken In ParseJSON("results")
            DGVLines.Rows.Add(1, result("fulfilments")(1)("instances")(1)("sku").ToString(), "", "EA", 1, 1)
        Next, but it doesn't want to do it for me, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @TomaszJ. You are writing it wrong, use visualizer then step trough it, it's easier that way.                    Instances holds {} not [], for {} (single items) you write the name, for [] (arrays) you write index. https://i.imgur.com/NNWWWsW.png

Comment: and to get to ship_address? I'm trying with below, following train of thought, but it's not working? :         For Each result As JToken In ParseJSON("ship_address")
            TextBox6.Text = result("street").ToString()
            TextBox9.Text = result("city").ToString()
            TextBox10.Text = result("zip_code").ToString() 
            TextBox11.Text = result("country").ToString() 
        Next

Comment: If you are starting with ship_address then of course it wont work as it's located ("results")(X)("ship_address")(other info here), eg  TextBox6.Text=ParseJSON("results")(0)("ship_address")("street").ToString

Comment: ParseJSON is your whole JSON (I assume) so you are located at the root  (the very first {), then you need to step trough the item to get to what you want. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ When you validate it, click to collapse everything, then find what you want.

Comment: amazing, thanks @CruleD! it all starting to make sense now, thank you!

Comment: @CruledD , and how can i get every single ShipmentId with LINQ if my JSON looks like this (list?) (i simplified it for the question) : [{"ShipmentId": "IMK TEST1"},{"ShipmentId": "IMK TEST4"},{"ShipmentId": "IMK TEST8"},{"ShipmentId": "IMK TEST9"}]

Comment: In some loop, If that example is not related to original json then For each item in Array debug.print(Item("ShipmentId").ToString) Next of course, "array" being a proper pointer.

Comment: Different JSON - same program, to put into DataGridView as well, I tried: Dim ParseJSON As JArray = JArray.Parse(jobj)
        DGVSnap.Rows.Clear()

        For Each result As JArray In ParseJSON
            DGVSnap.Rows.Add(result("ShipmentId").ToString(), result("Stage").ToString(), result("DateShipment").ToString())
            a += 1
        Next but it doesn't want to work, where's the mistake?

Comment: Again, great help in pointin me in the right direction - i found the mistake, thank you @CruleD!